# Network manager disappeared

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, networkmanager

My NetworkManager icon has disappeared and there is no network management tools in the menu. How do I get the icon back and an entry in the menu for configuring different wireless networks?

[image: No network manager - not even in the menu]

I use XFCE on GNU/Linux Mint, and the process NetworkManager runs (and finds my default access point just fine - but I do not get a chance to change access points).